# Grails domain class query - how can I find by fields that link to another domain class?

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

Lets say I have two domain classes:

```
class User {
  String name
  Role role
}

class Role {
  String name
  static belongsTo = [user: User]
}
```

and I create some records:

```
def r1 = new Role(name: "role1").save()
def r2 = new Role(name: "role2").save()
new User(name: "user1", role: r1).save()
new User(name: "user2", role: r2).save()
new User(name: "user3", role: r1).save()
```

How can I now select my users by role? I would expect to be able to do one of the following:

```
def role = Role.findByName("role1"); //returns a Role with [ id:1 name:"role1" ]
User.findAllByRole(role) //returns null
User.findAllByRole(new Role(name: "role1")) //returns null
User.findAllByRole(role.id) //returns null
User.findAllByRole(id: role.id) //returns null
```

Is it possible for a domain class to find other associated domain classes using the dynamic find* methods? I can do it using namedQueries, but id rather not because I dont want to have to write them out for *every* relationship I have between domain classes

Comment: Actually, I appear to be an idiot. User.findAllByRole(role) works now

Comment: What wasn't working about it? If it was less than straightforward, you could write an answer to your own question and accept it so that people having the same problem in the future might be helped by it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the findBy* and findAllBy* methods DO work, if you retrieve the object you need to find beforehand. It appears that it must be an exact (non-stale?) reference to an object in the database, so you cannot create a new object that "looks" like the object you want to find by, it actually has to *be* that object.

So, in order to find all the Users with the role of "role1":

```
def role = Role.findByName("role1")
def users = User.findAllByRole(role)
for (def user in users) {
 println("User ${user.name} matched the query, with role: ${user.role.name}")
}
//prints:
//User user1 matched the query, with role role1
//User user3 matched the query, with role role1
```

Comment: FYI: The code in your question *was* retrieving the role using a find. It wasn't just creating one with the same data.

Comment: I don't think def in (def user in users) is required.  for (user in users) {} should work fine.

Comment: I think your answer is conflicting with your question.In your question you have this: def role = Role.findByName("role1"); //returns a Role with [ id:1 name:"role1" ]
User.findAllByRole(role) //returns null                              Why is this returning null?  You are not creating a new object here. tht is what @JavidJamae is saying I think.

Answer (score 0):

`User.findAllByRole(role)` doesn't work on unit tests. I believe that's what confused you, Erin.

It seems Querying Associations isn't possible under unit tests. I've tried it this way: `User.findAllByRole(role.id)` and it works although not outside unit tests.

Comment: Haha 5 years later... I gave up on Grails a long time ago. At the time, it was bloated, incredibly slow and a nightmare to develop on. It might be better now, I dont know. I've been leaning towards pure Spring recently after a stint in .NET land

Comment: I'm sorry to disturb you. I was having this same problem and this thread was my top hit when googling so I felt I should add something to it. I'm enjoying Grails quite a lot (coming from Java+Spring+Hibernate).

Comment: Oh I have no problem with your answer, it contributes to the pool of knowledge which is awesome. Thanks for taking the time to post it!